# How to create stack views with constraints to the parent view's margins in Interface Builder?

Tags: swift, interface-builder, constraints

I want to have a horizontal stack view, or other view, constrain to the width of the view's margins.

I first add my interface elements.

(Image 1)

When I put them in a stack, they resize to (what I understand) are their intrinsic content sizes? Okay.

(Image 2)

At this point, the items turn red if selected. When I click the "update frames" button in the Interface Builder they get bigger and bigger. Until they extend right off the screen. What is going on? Why would updating frames make them grow beyond the confines of the screen?

(Image 3)

Okay... maybe I can ctrl-drag between the stack and the view now and pick constraints based on the view's margins, right? Maybe that will fix it...

[let's constrain our stack so it will resize the way I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh1i5.png)

Weird thing is, it doesn't matter if I click and drag from the view to the stack or from the stack to the view... either way I end up with constraints that seem to describe the REVERSE of what I want.

[Not what I meant!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UagpY.png)

I want to use the View's margins to define the Stack View's width, not the other way around! Also, they added 67.5 for some reason.

Thankfully there's a place to reverse these and remove the 67.5, right? I click on the constraint and make the changes...

(Image 6)

And now I'm in pretty good shape. I think. I mean it looks terrible, but at least they're in a stack... how do I set a minimum value for the label?

(Image 7)

Thanks for any commentary. Humor and poking fun at a newbie is welcome. Images reduced to 2 because I don't have reputation.

Comment: when you put them into the stack view you need to then constrain the stack view's position. Also you want the opposite i believe, drag stackview to view and constrain it to equal widths as oppose to the other way around (what your image is showing)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! It doesn't matter which way I drag, the Interface Builder does it the wrong way. Also, I do not want to constrain to equal widths, I want to use the margin guides of the View... which is why I made the selection shown. Any theories on why update frames makes the stack's contents get bigger and bigger until they stretch off the screen?

Comment: (Amusingly, if I create a constraint to equal widths, the stack view immediately resizes to jump off the screen.)

Comment: Can you provide which type of view it is? (TableView, Collection view, etc). and all the constraints that are currently active on that view? Maybe you're setting a bunch of constraints.

Comment: Hi, nope, no constraints. I am not sure what you mean by "which type of view it is". I started a new project, which had a "ViewController.swift" file and a "Main.storyboard". I put UILabels and controls onto the storyboard, lining them up with the automatic margins that showed up in the Interface Builder. I have also dragged them to the ViewController and created Outlets and Actions. I wanted to experiment with stacks, so I selected some labels and controls and clicked the button to create a stack.